# Access to mangled name within function works, but outside function not

Tags: python

There is this code:

```
class A:
  __x = 2

  def f(self):
    print(dir(self)) # there is attribute _A__x, but not __x
    print(self.__x) # prints 2
    print(self._A__x) # prints 2

x = A()
x.f()
print(x.__x) # AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute '__x'
```

Why access to `__x` variable is allowed inside method like `self.__x` but not outside this method? I know that name with two underscores is mangled, but the question is what is special so that this unmangled version works inside the method altough `self` has only mangled version as attribute.

Edit:

I noticed that if some attribute is added to the class with name of form `_A__name` for example:

```
class A:
  _A__y = 3

  def f(self):
    print(self.__y) # prints 3
    print(self._A__y) # prints 3

x = A()
x.f()
```

then inside class it seems that when for example interpreter looks for variable `__y` he can take also `_A__y` name, so it seems that prefix `_A` works something similar like scope resolution in C++ like `A::`. But I am not sure about details how it works.

So the original question can be extended why in this case `self.__y` has the same effect as `self._A__y` altough only `_A__y` is defined?

Comment: Google Python private class attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An attribute which is named with two leading underscores is "hidden" for use outside of the class (not really see below). It is a similar thing as private attributes in other languages.

An important thing is that you **can't** access the attribute from outside of the class with `x.__x` but you **can** access it with `x._A__x`. Inside of the class you can use (as you showed in the example) both ways.

In other languages like C++ you would declare your `__x` as private and than you can use it inside the class as `__x` and outside you can't. In python it is similar, because you use it inside also as `__x` and outside you shouldn't use it.

Look [here](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private) for the documentation of this behavior.

Comment: `and outside you can't` you actually still can access private attribute in C++, through some pointer math or by typecasting to another type. Accessing "private" attribute is just a slightly harder in C++ than in Python.

Answer (score 1):

`self.__x` will be mangled and turned in to `self._A__x`, that's why it works. Mangling is only done in code inside the class definition.